# Вылетает из приложения после загрузки

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно получить некоторую информацию с сайта и вывести ее на экран. На хабре нашел статейку, где все это реализуется с помощью HtmlCleaner .
По примеру я создал такое приложение. 
Захожу в приложение - Нажимаю кнопку - Появляется прогресс - И после из приложения выходит "В приложении произошла ошибка".
Вот код приложения:

index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/parse"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="Получить данные">
</Button>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listViewData"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

IndexActivity:

```
public class IndexActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        //Находим кнопку
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.parse);
        //Регистрируем onClick слушателя
        button.setOnClickListener(myListener);
      }

      //Диалог ожидания
      private ProgressDialog pd;
      //Слушатель OnClickListener для нашей кнопки
      private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //Показываем диалог ожидания
          pd = ProgressDialog.show(IndexActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
          //Запускаем парсинг
          new ParseSite().execute("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }
      };

      private class ParseSite extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {
        //Фоновая операция
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg) {
          List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
          try
          {
            HtmlHelper hh = new HtmlHelper(new URL(arg[0]));
            List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("question-hyperlink");

            for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = links.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
              TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
              output.add(divElement.getText().toString());
            }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return output;
        }

        //Событие по окончанию парсинга
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
          //Убираем диалог загрузки
          pd.dismiss();
          //Находим ListView
          ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
          //Загружаем в него результат работы doInBackground
          listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(IndexActivity.this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , output));
        }
      }
    }
```

HtmlHelper:

```
public class HtmlHelper {
    TagNode rootNode;



    public HtmlHelper(URL htmlPage) throws IOException {
        //Создаём объект HtmlCleaner
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        //Загружаем html код сайта
        rootNode = cleaner.clean(htmlPage);
    }

    List<TagNode> getLinksByClass(String CSSClassname)
    {
    List<TagNode> linkList = new ArrayList<TagNode>();

    //Выбираем все ссылки
    TagNode linkElements[] = rootNode.getElementsByName("a", true);
    for (int i = 0; linkElements != null && i < linkElements.length; i++)
    {
      //получаем атрибут по имени
      String classType = linkElements[i].getAttributeByName("class");
      //если атрибут есть и он эквивалентен искомому, то добавляем в список
      if (classType != null && classType.equals(CSSClassname))
      {
        linkList.add(linkElements[i]);
      }
      }

      return linkList;
     }
     }
```

Логи ошибок LogCat 1:
[image: LogCat 1]

LogCat 2:[image: LogCat 2]

Comment: думаю ошибка где то здесь `List<TagNode> links = hh.getLinksByClass("question-hyperlink");` почему название класса указано `question-hyperlink`?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev а какое должно быть название класса?

Comment: я незнаю. я только посмотрел где ошибка.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev название класса правильное. по идее программа парсит инфу которая внутри этого класса

Comment: Может быть имя-то и правильное, да вот пакет ведь кастомный - вероятно, неверно подключили его. Система сборки - gradle? Про dependencies не забыли?

Comment: @0xFFh простите, я в Android не давно. Не могли бы вы помочь мне решить данную проблему?

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать. Нужно проект целиком глянуть бы..

Comment: @0xFFh куда я могу вам его отправить?